# sql to filter decimal and non decimal integer in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have following table

```
marks
45
45.5
56
56
56.6
```

I need to write a query to list the marks which are not in decimal value i.e

```
marks
45
56
56
```

Is there any sql query to filter decimal and non decimal integer in sql server

Comment: what use could "a query to list the marks which are not in decimal value" be?  And what is the column type?

Answer (score 8):

Perhaps:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.Table1
   WHERE CEILING(marks) = FLOOR(marks)
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b5c7a/1/0)</kbd>

[**Comparing CEILING and FLOOR**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190927%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Comment: Tim I think OP is only looking for whole numbers from the column not rounded down numbers.

Comment: @M.Ali: yes, that's why the `WHERE`-clause filters for integers.

Comment: Sorry im still half sleep I thought you had used it in select :S

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM t
WHERE value NOT LIKE '%.%'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @t TABLE ( marks NUMERIC(10,2))
INSERT INTO @t VALUES 
(45),(45.5),(56),(56),(56.6)

SELECT marks 
FROM @t 
WHERE  marks = ROUND(marks , 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server 2012 you can use `[TRY_PARSE][1]`:

In the beneath example TRY_PARSE returns an INT when the value is an INT, else it returns NULL, so those rows are filtered out by the `IS NOT NULL`.

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE TRY_PARSE(CAST(Marks AS varchar(20)) AS INT) IS NOT NULL
```